# New E2C Threading - inbound message attaches to wrong case

Tags: email2case

We enabled the new [E2C threading behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1) some months ago in our PROD org.  One of our agents reported the following:

```
Timeline    Event                                        Result
T(0)        Inbound E2C from customer A                  Case 100 created
T(10-T(3)   Various emails back and forth w/ customer    emails added to Case 100
T(4)        Customer B creates web case                  Case 200 created
T(5)        Customer B sends email asking for follow-up  email attached to Case 100 !!!!!
```

Why did SFDC attach an email from Customer B to a case created by Customer A?

- I examined the headers on the email from Customer B at event T(5).  This email header includes lines used by SFDC to associate the inbound E2C email to a case.  These headers (redacted) were:

  ```
  References: <5008Z00001zFZZZ.XXXX.YYYYY=.8Z000000gOsc@sfdc.net>
  In-Reply-To: <5008Z00001zFZZZ.XXXX.YYYYY=.8Z000000gOsc@sfdc.net>
  ```

The value `5008Z00001zFZZZ` at the front of the header in fact is the Case Id for Case 100!

How did Customer B compose an email with headers relating to Customer A?  Customer A and B have no business relationship.

Comment: By any chance, did you also log this as a ticket with Salesforce Support and if yes, did you get a reply on it? I seem to have a similar issue right now

Comment: @svenf - I thought hard about logging a case but as we couldn't reproduce, I felt this was a fruitless exercise (based on many interactions with support over the last 10 years) - note that in spring 23, a [new threading model is being added](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_service_email_lightning_threading.htm&type=5&release=242) which perhaps fixes this issue